# Docker compose file

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and need help understanding Dockerfile.

Here is what I have currently:

```
version: "2"
services:
  foo:
    image: foo
    volumes_from: ["bar"]
    network_mode: "service:baz"
    environment:
      - "constraint:node==node-1"
  bar:
    image: bar
    environment:
      - "constraint:node==node-1"
  baz:
    image: baz
    environment:
      - "constraint:node==node-1"
```

I don't know how to show all field name of each service like: image, volume_from, environment etc.

Is it also possible to change `environment` text to `myenvironment` ?

Comment: I suppose you're looking for [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/).

Comment: @Dai it is right, thanks so much Dai